# Cant use methods on jquery code ('#' + add)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, methods

I have code like this:

```
for (i = 20; i <= to; i = i + 20)
{
    var add = parseInt(from + i);
    var findById = ('#' + add).find("img").attr("src");                           
}
```

And I am getting error:

`Object #28 has no method 'find'`

Can anyone help me?
Why I cannot use `.find` or `.attr` on object like this `('#' + add)`, but I can use these methods on simple `('#id')`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `$` in front of the bracket.

This

```
('#' + add)
```

should be

```
$('#' + add)
```